# Export specific numbers from Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

[So i have this column of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkNUE.png) and i wish to extract only the numbers before the "HE" text [for example, this is what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuzbq.png), and i don't really know how to achieve this.

Maybe there is a way to use a formula or command to do this, i've been trying to use power tools add-on but to no avail i did not get it.

Maybe for clarification in each cell there are 2 lines, using alt+enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REGEXEXTRACT()` is suitable in this case.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.+) HE")
```

Few good tips [here](https://productivityspot.com/regexextract-google-sheets/) about `REGEXEXTRACT()`.

For array approach use below formula-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A1:A="","",REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"(.+) HE")))
```

[image]